# How to make an sh script execute commands in terminal

Tags: bash, scripts

I have recently developed an habit of programming. I saw this tutorial that allows me to use a program called SearXNG which allows me to make my own private search engine. ([BTW click here for the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifT6npY39Dw)) This has made me have to execute this command in particular to run the Search Engine:

```
cd searxng-docker && sudo docker-compose up -d
```

(BTW the cd is there because searxng-docker is the directory where the code is installed)

Now i want to create an sh script that if I run then the Search engine will automically start. I have seen multiple tutorials that show me how to code in sh scripts but not one have I found useful.

```
exec cd searxng-docker && sudo docker-compose up -d
```

I tried to put this into the script, and it opened the terminal, but did not execute the command. How do i fix this?

Comment: I don't understand what "the terminal" means here. Are you launching a new gnome-terminal (or some other) and expect to see output in that window?

Comment: @gienn By the terminal i mean that i want that command to be executed in bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...thanks all the people that tried to answer my question but i found the answer myself. So if you are trying to find the answer to this question, look no farther than this.

First a little bit of clarification. All .sh scripts can be made to run bash commands. You just have to add the SHEBANG line to do so.

The SHEBANG line specifies which application will be used to run the script. This application can be anything from Python to Bash.

To make the script run with bash what we do is type this at the starting of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Now that we've added the SHEBANG line, all of the lines in this script will be run as bash commands.

Next, we can simply add the commands that we wanted to execute. Now the script will be looking something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd searxng-docker
sudo docker-compose up -d
```

Now there is a simple change we CAN make to make the script a little bit more efficient. If you look at the `cd` line, you can see that we are cd-ing into the `searxng-docker` folder. This means  that the `cd` command is pointing to the relative location of the folder. This is bad as if we are in any other directory than our home directory, the cd command will not work.

To fix this, we have to replace the `cd searxng-docker` command with the `cd /home/<your-username>/searxng-docker` command. Don't forget to replace the `<your-username>` with your real username.

Now, just one problem remains. Making the script executable.

To do this, type in the terminal: `chmod +x ./<your-script-name>` and again, replace `<your-script-name>` with the name of the script you created.

Now your script is ready and you can execute it by right-clicking on the script and choosing "Run as a program" or by typing `./<your-script-name>` in the terminal, again replacing `<your-script-name>` with the name of the script you created.

Comment: In addition, you can do `sudo usermod -aG docker "$USER"` in order to add your user to the Docker's group (log-out/log-in), thus you will no longer need to use `sudo` when manage Docker.

Answer (score 0):

```
exec cd searxng-docker && sudo docker-compose up -d
```

First a general explanation before we come to your specific case. This command will first change directory (`cd` to `searxng-docker`). Only if that succeeds (`&&`), the following command will be run.

As currently written, the script requires you to be in the directory containing the `searxng-docker` directory. Else, the second command will not proceed.

To make sure the script can be started independently from the current directory, change the relative path `searxng-docker` to the absolute path (e.g. `/home/username/searxng-docker` if the directory resides in the home directory of user `usrname`).

In your particular case, since you change directory in order to find an executable, there is a much better solution: replace your entire line directly launching the executable by its absolute path name:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo /home/username/searxng-docker/docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Well... thanks but i already figured out a way to do that.